# Select Join com ultimo registro Mysql

Tags: mysql

Bom dia,

Estou com problemas em fazer essa busca no mysql:

Gostaria de obter todos os usuários ativos com suas ultimas viagens (ultimo registro):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comando utilizado:

```
SELECT u.id, t.user_id, u.name, u.status, t.name as last_trip
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN trips t ON u.id = t.user_id AND t.id = ( SELECT MAX(*) FROM trips)
WHERE u.status = 'active';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     SELECT u.id AS `user_id`, u.`name`, u.`status`,
       (SELECT t.`name` FROM trips t WHERE t.user_id = u.id ORDER BY t.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS `last_trip`
     FROM users u
     WHERE u.`status` = "active"
```

Essa provavelmente não é a solução perfeita, mas já resolve o seu problema.

Comment: E se caso eu quiser trazer todos os campos das 2 tabelas, sendo a tabela trips o ultimo registro?

Comment: `SELECT u.*, t.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN trips t ON t.user_id = u.id
WHERE t.id = (SELECT MAX(tr.id) FROM trips tr WHERE tr.user_id = u.id AND u.status = "active")`